# Not able to get Azure function to trigger on Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I've been trying to get started with Azure Event Hubs & Azure functions.
While following the exact documentation - I'm unable to get the event hub trigger to work.
I have the following setup:

Function I call in an HTTP function (to generate event logs):

```
 @EventHubOutput(name = "message-new", eventHubName = "KCETest1", connection = "KCETest1_all_EVENTHUB", dataType = "string" )
        public String sendOrder(ExecutionContext context) {
            return "foobar";
    }
```

Snapshot of my event hub showing events are being triggered:
[Event Hub Receiving messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkZf6.png)

However, I'm not able to get anything to work to trigger an azure function.
I tried all the below just to get at least something written to the logs.
(as you can see - I've been playing around with all variables - thinking this might be the rootcause)

```
public class EventHubTriggerJava1 {
    /**
     * This function will be invoked when an event is received from Event Hub.
     */
    @FunctionName("EventHubTriggerJava1")
    public void run(
        @EventHubTrigger(name = "msg", eventHubName = "KCETest1", connection = "KCETest1_all_EVENTHUB", consumerGroup = "$Default", cardinality = Cardinality.ONE , dataType = "string") String message,
        final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java Event Hub trigger 1function executed.");
        context.getLogger().info("Length:" + message);
    }

    @FunctionName("EventHubTriggerJava2")
    public void run(
        @EventHubTrigger(name = "msg2", eventHubName = "testhub1", connection = "KCETest1_all_EVENTHUB", consumerGroup = "$Default", cardinality = Cardinality.ONE) EventData message,
        final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java Event Hub trigger 2function executed.");
        context.getLogger().info("Length:" + message.toString());
    }

    @FunctionName("EventHubTriggerJava3")
    public void run(
        @EventHubTrigger(name = "msg3", eventHubName = "testhub1", connection = "KCETest1_all_EVENTHUB", consumerGroup = "$Default") List<String> message,
        final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java Event Hub trigger 3 function executed.");
        context.getLogger().info("Length:" + message.get(0).toString());
    }
}
```

I'm running out of ideas - any suggestions from your side?

Thx a lot!